# Close Alert in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is there anyway to close an alert in RN, so for example my app shows an alert when you go idle for a few seconds and there is 'YES' button in the alert when you pressed it it will refresh the timer and shows the alert again, and if i do nothing with the alert it goes to next page somehow the Alert still open in the next page and I want it to be closed. Thanks

here is my code

```js
componentDidMount(){
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.sessionTimeout, 3000); //auto reset after 60 seconds of inactivity
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }

    sessionTimeout(){
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.onSubmit, 3000)
        Alert.alert('You ran out of time', 'still editing?',
        [
          {text: 'YES', onPress:this.resetTimer.bind(this)}
        ],
        {cancelable: false}
        ) 
    }

    resetTimer(){
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.sessionTimeout, 3000);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant code segment so that it the problem could be understood.

Comment: ok done i added it

Comment: But still you have't added the code segment respective to the navigation to next page.

Comment: Check my answer below, is updated and its the solution.

Comment: i edited the description hope you get what i meant

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the cancelable option from the Alert:

```
 {cancelable: false}
```

Any button will work as a dismiss and it should close the alert on click.